# Why is ARM deployment with integer parameters not picked up by Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

When I deploy in Azure DevOps the ARM template below I get an error due to an integer was expected, but a string was found. If I explicitly change the variables to values it will be properly picked up. Any idea what is going on here?

I have a Release Pipeline which deploys an ARM Template with parameters (not working, found string but integer was expected):
[image]

This works since I changed the variable values to explicit integers (working, but I want to use variable groups):
[image]

In the variable groups I have defined the name and values as:
FaultDomains 2
UpdateDomains 5

ARM Template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "0.0.1.0",
    "parameters": {
        "AvailabilitySetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "FaultDomains": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "UpdateDomains": {
            "type": "int"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
            "name": "[parameters('AvailabilitySetName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "platformUpdateDomainCount": "[parameters('UpdateDomains')]",
                "platformFaultDomainCount": "[parameters('FaultDomains')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "Aligned"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does your template have a `"1"` instead of a `1` in the Fault/UpdateDomains param?  I found a while back that it worked, but now it seems it's validated and an int inside quotes fails validation.

Comment: Hi @SilentNinja, how are things going? Is `@ShantnuMatharoo`'s answer helpful to you? If it is helpful, please mark it as the solution. Feel free to tell us if you have any question about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the case and was able to deploy the availabilty set with given template using release pipeline,

[Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzYRo.png)

and make sure the parameteres are defined in the release variables.

NOTE: I used ARM TEMPLATE DEPLOYMENT task for deployment

[deployment results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqOqX.png)